# Align text and change amount of spaces

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to format my string, becouse i have two strings one that contain: "1" and the

second that contain: "test" and want to  output the whole string with space as:

**1   test**

i did that by saying:

```
printf("%-10s %s", "1", "test");
```

but how do i change the space  " %-10s " without changing the format?

```
int amount_of_space = 10;

like: printf("%-*s %s", "1", "test", amount_of_space)
```

how do i do that??? in C or C++, please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%-*s %s", amount_of_space, "1", "test" ) ;
```

The * comes first in the format string - hence the parameter `amount_of_space` has to come first after the comma.

i.e in the format string the order is *, s & s - so after the comma, you need whatever fills in for *, the first string and then the 2nd string.

Comment: I'm going pick your anwser as accepted in 6 min, becouse you are the only one who explained things to me :)

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%-*s %s", amount_of_space, "1", "test" );`

Answer (score 1):

use this:
`printf("%-*s %s", amount_of_space, "1", "test" );`

Answer (score 0):

And in C++ it would be:

```
cout << left << setw(amount_of_spaces) << "1" << "test";
```